# Битовые операции. Неправильный сдвиг

Tags: java, битовые-операции

Есть значение

```
byte b1 = (byte) 0xE2; //1110 0010
```

Из этого нужно получить значение 7 (десятичное) // 0111

Пробую сдвинуть на 5 разрядов вправо, получается 0xFF.

```
int result = b1 >> 5; // = 0xFF. А по идеи должно было получится 0000 0111 (значение 7 DEC)
```

Подскажите, что не так?

Правильный результат я получил с помощью BetSet.

```
BitSet result = getBitSet(new byte[] { b1 }, 0, 5, 3);
int dec = Arrays.copyOf(result.toByteArray(), 1)[0]; // = 7. b1 не всегда 0xE7, может быть и 0x2 и т.д. т.е. в этом случае в получаем просто 0

public static BitSet getBitSet(byte[] array, int fromByteIndex, int fromByteBitIndex, int bitsCount) {
    BitSet arrayBitSet = BitSet.valueOf(array);
    int fromIndex = fromByteIndex * 8 + fromByteBitIndex;
    return arrayBitSet.get(fromIndex, fromIndex + bitsCount);
}
```

Comment: Кстати, как именно звучит задача. Почему нужно получить именно 7? Нужно взять три первых бита?

Comment: Да, нужно взять 3 бита.

Comment: Для такого обычно используют маски. Посмотрите ответ МВо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`>>` - оператор арифметического сдвига (SAR), он распространяет знаковый бит, который в данном случае единичный

Но в Java есть и оператор `>>>` (логический или беззнаковый сдвиг), который заполнит освободившееся место нулями

```
int b1 =  0xE2; //1110 0010
int result = b1 >>> 5; 
System.out.print(result);

7
```

Поскольку при приведении байта к int происходит заполнение единицами, можно обнулить старшую часть промежуточного результата.

```
byte b1 =  (byte) 0xE2; //1110 0010
int result = (b1 & 0xFF) >>> 5; 
System.out.print(result);
```

В зависимости от задачи может оказаться проще наложить трёхбитовую маску 7 в конце.

```
int result = (b1 >>> 5) & 7;
```

Comment: Да, это верно для int, но не поможет для byte. Дело в том, что шестнадцатеричный код 0xE2 представляет положительное число в int, но отрицательное в byte. Из-за этого при приведении byte к int слева появляются лишние единицы.

Comment: Не работает для byte.

Comment: int result = (int) ((byte) 0xE2 >>> 5) - результат другой.

Comment: @DuosDuo Добавил с побитовым and.

Comment: Спасибо. А я не додумался применить трехбитовую маску :/. В общем, все ответы достойны быть принятыми, но принимаю ваш т.к. приведен пример решения. Всем спасибо!!

Answer (score 3):

Byte в яве сдвигать нельзя. Поэтому сначала он дополняется до int. В вашем случае единицами,  т.к. первый бит в вашем байте - единица.  Именно эти единицы и выходят потом в итоговом значении.

Полезная ссылка:  [How does bitshifting work in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312853/how-does-bitshifting-work-in-java) .

Comment: Ясно, спасибо.  Изучу ссылку.